# How do I supply Stripe product ID for checkout controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm working on building a Stripe store and I can't get past this error. It seems to be an issue as of a recent change to the Stripe API (https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#api-versions). The documentation (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration) gives som good code as starting point but, I can't figure out how it wants me to pass the product ID. The documentation shows it as ***product: '{{PRODUCT_ID}}'*** but it does not resolve. I have tried

```
product: product, 
product: '{{product.id}}', 
product: product.id, 
product: "#{product.id}",
```

None of these seem to be what the API is expected and I cannot get past this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create Product via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/create) your get a Product [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/object) with and `id` property that looks like `prod_123456`.

Other APIs will expect the Product id as a parameter, simply as a string. So for example you'd pass `product: 'prod_123456'`. If you have just created the Product and have it in a variable called `product` then you would just do `product: product.id` usually.

Comment: Okay, if I understand correctly, I am trying to pass the Rails product object * product = Product.find(params[:id]) * to the Stripe session but, it is expecting the Stripe product object. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it needs the `prod_12345` which is the Product id in Stripe